# How to create a Circle ListView on Android?

Tags: android, listview, layout, geometry

How to create a Circle ListView as lazy Swipe application.

[image: http://yosoyandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/9F0006AAE28C_Note-4_0_PORTRAIT-336x600.png]

Comment: Check out : https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu

Comment: define "lazy Swipe application."

Answer (score 3):

The [ArcLayout](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/ArcLayout) has great customizations to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It's called **C-Swipe**, take a look at this tutorial : [C-Swipe](http://www.athenna.com/an-ergonomic-solution-navigation-fragmentation-on-android/athenna/web_design/teoria-de-design/), or [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/25/c-swipe-navigation-on-android/)